# difference between entity name and Entity Set Name

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using .Net 3.5 with SP1.

This may be simple. But, I'm not sure about the difference between  entity name and Entity Set Name

Please help me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An entity name is a class name.

An entity set name is a query.

For example, you can have an entity named "Person" with an entity set named "People". This lets you write code like:

```
Person bob = Context.People.Where(p => p.Id == bobId).Single();
```